# How Does Any iOS Device Decide What Networks are Public?

Tags: ios, wifi

Per the title, some networks are marked as Public in the WiFi section of Settings, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In many router configurations, you can designate wifi networks as 'public' or 'open'. These do not enable encryption, and I suspect that for devices, these and other networks without encryption is considered public.